# How to navigate open programs in Awesome WM using arrow keys whilst in tile layout?

Tags: window-management, awesome-wm

In Awesome WM the way you switch between open programs is by going to the previous or next client. By default it uses the keybinding Mod4 + k and Mod4 + j respectively.

However, let say I have four clients open in my screen using the tile layout, whereas I have four tiles on screen showing each program. If currently I am on the top-left tile and I want to go to the bottom left, I need to press Mod4 + j twice, cycling to the top right before arriving at the bottom left. What I want is to go directly to that tile using a single keybinding, is that possible in Awesome. I know in i3 WM this is the default behaviour using the arrows keys to move up and down, left and right between open programs.

Comment: I come from i3 too and it's a pain not having this shortcut, thanks for your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default config doesn't provide keybindigns for this, but you are looking for [awful.client.focus.bydirection](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.client.html#client.focus.bydirection). For example, add a keybinding for this function:

```
function() client.focus.bydirection('down') end
```